# Retrieve Specific Data from Two Database Tables On the Bases Of CNIC

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an application for Real Estate.
In this i have two tables named `Registration` and `Transitory_Letter`.
I want to fetch two value from `Registration` table "`serial_no` and `application_date`" and 4 values from `Transitory_Letter` table.

```
 $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM transitory where cnic='$_POST[nic]'
 UNION
 SELECT serial_no,application_date FROM Registration where cnic='$_POST[nic]'";
 $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
  While ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $rs ))
{

     $serial = $row["serial_no"];
     $name = $row["name"];
     $so = $row["so"];
     $nic = $row["cnic"];
     $add = $row["address"];
     $date = $row["Date"];
     $days = $row["days_given"];
     $size = $row["plot_size"];
     $app = $row["application_date"];

             print "

               <tr><td align=right>$serial</td></tr>";
                print "


               <tr><td align=right>$app</td></tr>";
               print "
               <tr><td align=right>$appdate</td></tr><br /><br />";
               print "
               <tr><td align=right>$lda</td></tr>";
                print "
               <tr><td align=right>$ldadate</td></tr><br />";
               print "
               <tr><td align=right>$days</td></tr><br /><br /><br />";
                        print "
                        <tr><td><p style=' letter-spacing:1px; margin-left:200px;margin-top:-10px;'><strong>$size</strong></p></td></tr>";
                        print "
                        <tr><td><p style='letter-spacing:1px; margin-left:200px;margin-top:-25px;'><strong>$name</strong></p></td></tr><br />";
                        print "
                         <tr><td><p style='letter-spacing:1px; margin-left:200px;margin-top:-50px;'><strong>$so</strong></p></td><tr><br /><br />";
                print "
                        <tr><td><p style=' margin-left:200px;margin-top:-65px;'>$nic</p></td></tr><br />";
                print "                           <tr><td><p style=' margin- left:200px;margin-top:-50px;'>$add</p>

</td></tr><br />";
                          print "<tr><td align=right>$serial</td></tr><br /><br /> <br/>";




// Close the database connection
mysql_close();
```

}

But it does not return any data.
Please tell me how can I get data by using correct query.

Comment: You should place $variables in ' ' tags, like

`print "<td>"'.$variable.'"</td>";`

Comment: But if i only get data from one table this script works fine. problem is that it does not show data from 2 tables at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite sql query in this way:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT t.*, r.serial_no, r.application_date FROM transitory AS t INNER JOIN 
Registration AS r ON t.cnic='".$_POST['nic']."' 
WHERE r.cnic='".$_POST['nic']."'";
```